# What does a 0 minute boil time mean?

Tags: beer, boil, wort

I have a recipe that calls for an ounce of hops at 0 mins. boil time, any idea what you would do here?

Typically, after a my 60 minute partial boil is complete, I take the pot off of the stove immediately, remove  the hop bag from the wort (which contains all the hop pellets), and put in my wort chiller to cool down the wort immediately. So I don't really have a 0 minute boil time ... unless I put the hops in the hop bag just for a couple seconds or so just before removing, and if I did do that, I don't know that it would really be long enough to have any effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means putting an addition of hops at flameout, or when you turn off the kettle. Those late addition hops can add hop aroma and some nice flavor.

I wouldn't take your hops out when the boil is done for hoppy beers. Leaving those hops in while the wort cools can give you more of that aroma that some styles call for.

Jamil Zainasheff published an article called [The Secret to Big Hop Aroma and Flavor](http://www.mrmalty.com/late_hopping.php) that I've found very helpful.

Comment: OK. My reasoning for removing the hops at flameout was as follows ... I also added hops at 10 min. boil time for aroma/flavoring, and I was thinking that if I left them sit in the wort as it cooled that some of the flavor and aroma might burn off as the wort is still relatively hot for the first few minutes while it begins to cool. However, it sounds like you are saying that the opposite is true, that leaving them in while it cools will add more flavor and aroma.

Comment: That's my understanding, yes.

Comment: OK, great article by the way. It seems like he sort of touches on this topic in the "Other Tips for Late Hopping" section. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You're right; I actually missed that the first time through. So perhaps an addition just after the chilling is complete? It sounds like experiment time...

Comment: @sqwill: In my 0 boil time, my chilling is started almost synchronized with the flame out with about 5 seconds of delay.  And I reach about 60C (140F) in less than 3 mins. Should I worry about that if my '0 boil time hop addition'  start 30 seconds or more from flame out? What time range should I worry? Or should I prefer to add hop before to start the chilling?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the times given for hop additions indicate the length of time the hops are to be boiled for, which is the length of time until the end of the boil.  So, for examle, if a recipe said:

```
1  oz. at 60 min.
.5 oz. at 15 min.
1  oz. at  0 min,
```

if you boil started at 9:00, you'd put in 1 oz. at 9:00, .5 oz at 9:45, and 1 oz. at 10:00.  And you'd turn the heat off at 10:00.

Hops contribure more bitterness and less aroma the earlier they are added to the boil, and they contribute less bitterness and more aroma the later they are added.  Those ones you are supposed to add at 0 min. are for aroma.

Comment: I think his question is more along the lines of. I take my hops out as soon as I take my kettle off the heat, will adding my hops for 10 seconds make a difference? Or should I change my procedure

Comment: Nathan, you should change your procedure.  Once the hops go in, leave them in.  That's the way recipes are usually constructed.

Comment: @Denny, so leave them in until the wort is chilled and goes into the fermenter, right? If so, that is what I was missing here...

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I'm use a plate chiller and a false bottom in my boil kettle.   I usually handle this in one of two ways.  At flame out I would add hops and let it sit for 15 mins before running it through the chiller.  Or, since the intent is mostly to add aroma I'd add to or include it in my dry hop.